# 400 Bad Request when sending JSON from JS to Java

Tags: java, json, web-services

I have a webservice in m webapp with following signature:

```
public void addSkill(@RequestBody String ldapid, @RequestBody TechnologyUI skill)
{...}
```

and I send JSON request which looks like:

```
"{"ldapid":"msmith","skill":{"description":"Java","id":7}}"
```

The TechnologyUI class looks like this:

```
public class TechnologyUI {

private String description;
private Integer id;
// constructors
// getters/setters
}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, for me this request looks exactly as it's supposed to look. Can anyone see what's wrong with it?

Comment: can you add how you are sending the request? might be the content type. also, do the quote around the json request appear in the payload?

Comment: Try adding quotes to 7. "id":"7". Have you used a JSON validator?

Comment: There are no quotes in payload. @Fede but 7 is supposed to go as Integer - why quotes?

Comment: just to test if your value comes as string

Comment: Strictly speaking, json is untyped, so even ints should be quoted

Comment: Have you tried creating a class that has a String ldapid and a TechnologyUI skill and reducing the addSkill input to one variable of the new type?

Comment: I did and it kinda works, but that's not ideal for me